# python os.makedirs Error 13 permission denied

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, file-upload

I have a server set up on apache.

So when i run it and i upload a few files from a different machine. The server crashes here..

```
os.makedirs('data/%d' % stat.id)
```

The server crashes and it gives me this error

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'data'

I have googled it and looked at other posts, I tried, but nothing works. 
I have tried changing the group and chmod, chown..

Comment: Do you have apparmor enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache was making a directory under root.

I had to change the directory and it works.

```
os.chdir('...')
```

And when i create directory, its fine.